# combining 2 text file and make a new one in python

Tags: python

I have 2 big text files like the following small examples. there are 2 files (`major and minor`).
in both `major` and `minor` files there are 4 columns. in the major file the difference between 2nd and 3rd columns in 10000 and the difference between 2nd and 3rd columns is 32 or 31 or a number close to 31 but not so high.

small example of major file:

```
chr4    530000  540000  0.0
chr4    540000  550000  1719.0
chr4    550000  560000  0.0
```

small example of minor file:

```
chr4    295577  295608  12
chr4    323326  323357  10
chr4    548873  548904  32
chr4    548873  548904  20
chr4    549047  549078  32
chr4    549047  549078  20
chr4    549137  549168  32
chr4    549137  549168  20
chr4    549181  549212  32
chr4    549181  549212  20
chr4    549269  549300  22
chr4    549269  549300  381
chr4    549269  549300  67
chr4    549269  549300  89
chr4    549269  549300  95
chr4    549269  549300  124
chr4    549269  549300  149
chr4    549269  549300  87
chr4    549269  549300  33
chr4    549269  549300  65
chr4    549269  549300  68
chr4    549269  549300  190
chr4    549269  549300  20
chr4    549355  549386  32
chr4    549355  549386  20
chr4    549443  549474  16
chr4    705810  705841  10
chr4    846893  846924  28
```

I want to make a new text file in which there would be 4 columns. like the expected output:

expected output:

```
chr4    548873  548904  32  chr4    540000  550000
chr4    548873  548904  20  chr4    540000  550000
chr4    549047  549078  32  chr4    540000  550000
chr4    549047  549078  20  chr4    540000  550000
chr4    549137  549168  32  chr4    540000  550000
chr4    549137  549168  20  chr4    540000  550000
chr4    549181  549212  32  chr4    540000  550000
chr4    549181  549212  20  chr4    540000  550000
chr4    549269  549300  22  chr4    540000  550000
chr4    549269  549300  381 chr4    540000  550000
chr4    549269  549300  67  chr4    540000  550000
chr4    549269  549300  89  chr4    540000  550000
chr4    549269  549300  95  chr4    540000  550000
chr4    549269  549300  124 chr4    540000  550000
chr4    549269  549300  149 chr4    540000  550000
chr4    549269  549300  87  chr4    540000  550000
chr4    549269  549300  33  chr4    540000  550000
chr4    549269  549300  65  chr4    540000  550000
chr4    549269  549300  68  chr4    540000  550000
chr4    549269  549300  190 chr4    540000  550000
chr4    549269  549300  20  chr4    540000  550000
chr4    549355  549386  32  chr4    540000  550000
chr4    549355  549386  20  chr4    540000  550000
chr4    549443  549474  16  chr4    540000  550000
```

the first 4 columns are from the `minor file` and the last 3 columns are from the `major file`. 
looking at the expected output the number in the `2nd` and `3rd` columns (from minor file) are in the range of the same row but `columns 6` and 7 (from major file) and 1st column is equal to the `5th` column (in fact the 1st columns of both major and minor files). 
in fact I want to look for the rows in minor file in which the first column is equal to the 1st column of major file, also `2nd` and `3rd` columns of the same row (in minor file) must be in a range of `2nd` and the `3rd` columns in the major file. so in fact there are 3 conditions for every row in the minor file to be eligible to be included in the output file. and the last 3 columns are from the major file which fit the rows from minor file.

I am trying to do that in python and have made the following code but it does not return what I expected:

```
major = open("major.txt", 'rb')
minor = open("minor.txt", 'rb')
major_list = []
minor_list = []
for m in major:
    major_list.append(m)

for n in minor:
    minor_list.append(n)

final = []
for i in minor_list:
    for j in major_list
    if minor_list[i] == major_list[j] and minor_list[i+1] <= major_list[j+1] and minor_list[i+2] >= major_list[j+2]:
        final.append(i)


with open('output.txt', 'w') as f:
    for item in final:
        f.write("%s\n" % item)
```

Comment: you may want to look into using the `zip` function when looping over 2 lists simultaneously. You would write `for i, j in zip(minor_list, major_list):` then you can access each at the same time so you do not need to do the following check for equality. both `i` and `j` will be the values of there respective lists and walk through it together.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe its a typo in your code I can see that your missing a tab at your if minor_list[i]

```
final = []
for i in minor_list:
    for j in major_list
    if minor_list[i] == major_list[j] and minor_list[i+1] <= major_list[j+1] and minor_list[i+2] >= major_list[j+2]:
        final.append(i)
```

should be

```
final = []
for i in minor_list:
    for j in major_list
        if minor_list[i] == major_list[j] and minor_list[i+1] <= major_list[j+1] and minor_list[i+2] >= major_list[j+2]:
            final.append(i)
```

Answer (score 0):

You should do something like this

```
final = []
for i, j in zip(minor_list, major_list):
    final.append(i, j)
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you HAVE to use Python for this? If you install "bedtools" in bash shell, this can be accomplished with the following line:

`bedtools intersect -wa -wb -a minor.bed -b major.bed > intersected_file.bed`

A few bioinformatics tools are linux/mac-only, so if you're going to be doing any amount of bioinformatics, it's worth learning how to script in shell.